# How to use preg_match to search from a string, including a symbol?

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a pattern `status: available`, but the colon symbol doesn't work somehow. How to modify this patern?

I have messed something in the code, will notify you when I find it. Thank You

OK I broke down the code. I'm writing a script for domain avalability.

```
<?php
$server = 'whois.cira.ca';
$pattern = 'status: available';

$domain = 'nonexistingdomain';
$extension = '.ca';

$buffer = NULL;
$sock = fsockopen($server, 43) or die('Error Connecting To Server: ' . $server);
fputs($sock, $domain.$extension . "\r\n");

while( !feof($sock) )
{
    $buffer .= fgets($sock,128);
}

//If I give a value localy to $buffer (like below) it works, but if $buffer takes the value from fgets() function it wont
$buffer = "Domain name: nonexistingdomain.ca Domain status: available % WHOIS look-up made at 2013-01-16 12:35:45 (GMT) % % Use of CIRA's WHOIS service is governed by the Terms of Use in its Legal % Notice, available at http://www.cira.ca/legal-notice/?lang=en % % (c) 2013 Canadian Internet Registration Authority, (http://www.cira.ca/) NO";

fclose($sock);

if(preg_match("/$pattern/", $buffer))
    echo "YEP";
else
    echo "NO";
?>
```

If I change $pattern to "available" it works!

Comment: Can you give the full line of code where this preg_match is?

Comment: Please provide the full code so we can help. input, pattern, output..

Comment: Try to change the last `if` into `if(preg_match('/status: available/', $buffer))`

Comment: @Martin nothing. It is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing a delimeter.

Try this:

```
<?php

$pattern = '/status: available/';

$string = "String1: status: available";
$string1 = "String2: status: unavailable";


if (preg_match($pattern,$string))
    echo 'String1 matches<br>';
else
    echo 'String1 does not match<br>';

if (preg_match($pattern,$string1))
    echo 'String2 matches<br>';
else
    echo 'String 2 does not match<br>';
?>
```

Gives the following output:

`String1 matches`

`String 2 does not match`

Comment: @XhevatZiberi - the code given in this answer will not cause that error.

Comment: @XhevatZiberi Maybe give some more info on the question, like what are you trying to filter. Because the way I wrote it works for me on a simple string containing 'status: available'.

Comment: @Tuim I updated my question look at the comment I added. You can try the code. It is very wierd